# Side button on iPhone 7 doesn't silent anymore but declines the call

Tags: iphone

Until today I was able to silent a call (both from ringing and on silent/vibrate modes) on my iPhone 7 plus with the lock button on the right.
When I press it now, it just declines the call on both modes.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What have you already tried to solve this yourself?  You can [edit] your question to add that info.  This will help in preventing people from suggesting solutions you've already tried (but didn't work).

Comment: Are you pressing it twice by accident? My iPhone 6 silences it on the first press, and declines on the second press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under iOS 10 and earlier, the side/power button was responsible for silencing a call, just as you'd experienced. But now, under iOS 11, the volume keys — maybe just the Volume Down button? — are responsible for silencing a call. The side/power button remains the way to decline a call.

If you've recently installed iOS 11 on your iPhone, that may explain the change in functionality you've observed.

So, the next time you get a call, try pressing the Volume Down button and see if that achieves the effect you want.

Comment: I just tried, I’m on iOS 11 and the lock button is still silencing the call.

Comment: @Chris when you press the lock button, does the screen show that the call is still incoming (that it's still ringing on the caller's end)? Or is the call silenced and ended, sending the caller straight to voicemail?

Comment: When I first press the button, the call is still incoming, when I second press, the caller is sent to my voicemail

Comment: Thank you!!!! Both the Volume Up and Volume Down button silence the call.  The right hand button declines the call. Thanks! I'm now not hanging up on everyone that calls me!

Answer (score 0):

Had you tried to restore your iPhone ?

Maybe if you go to an Apple Store to show your problem at the Genius Bar, they’ll be capable to repair your problem (if you have AppleCare+)